# How can a list comprehension do this

Tags: python, odoo, list-comprehension

In this code below, a list is being iterated though, and a dictionary built of 2 values for each entry in the list. The dictionaries and then added to a new list.

The code below works, see below for the results of the print statements.

But is it possible to do this in a cleaner way, perhaps with a list comprehension?

```
ccdl_rows = ccdl_obj.browse(self.cr, self.uid, ccdl_ids)
    print 'ccdl_rows:', ccdl_rows
    dist_lines = []
    for ccdl in ccdl_rows:
        dist_line = {}
        dist_line['destination'] = ccdl.destination_id.code
        dist_line['cost_center'] = ccdl.analytic_id.code
        dist_lines.append(dist_line)
    print 'dist_lines: ', dist_lines

ccdl_rows: [browse_record(cost.center.distribution.line, 12), browse_record(cost.center.distribution.line, 13), browse_record(cost.center.distribution.line, 14)]

dist_lines:  [{'cost_center': u'BI133', 'destination': u'SUP'}, {'cost_center': u'MW109', 'destination': u'SUP'}, {'cost_center': u'BI196', 'destination': u'SUP'}]
```

Comment: Why not create the dictionary inline? `[{'keys': and, 'values': here} for ccdl in ccdl_rows]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course:

```
dist_lines = [{'cost_center': ccdl.analytic_id.code,
               'destination': ccdl.destination_id.code}
              for ccdl in ccdl_rows]
```